# Run python script only if it's not running

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I want to launch a python script from another python script. I know how to do it. But I should launch this script only if it is not running already.

**code:**

```
import os
os.system("new_script.py")
```

But I'm not sure how to check if this script is already running or not.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110698/how-to-check-which-specific-processes-python-scripts-are-running might be of help

Comment: Something simple like `pgrep -f 'new_script.py'|| ./new_script.py` or you have to use a lockfile with the PID.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
import subprocess
import os 

p = subprocess.Popen(['pgrep', '-f', 'your_script.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()

if len(out.strip()) == 0:
    os.system("new_script.py")
```

Answer (score 3):

Came across this old question looking for solution myself.

Use [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil):

```
import psutil
import sys
from subprocess import Popen

for process in psutil.process_iter():
    if process.cmdline() == ['python', 'your_script.py']:
        sys.exit('Process found: exiting.')

print('Process not found: starting it.')
Popen(['python', 'your_script.py'])
```

You can also use start time of the previous process to determine if it's running too long and might be hung:

```
process.create_time()
```

There is tons of other useful metadata of the process.