# Run python script one time until to end

Tags: python

If I execute my long-running Python script multiple times in a row, multiple instances of that script will be running in parallel. But I want that as long as the first instance runs, the others should exit immediately without doing anything. When the first instance exited, the next instance should run again, and so on. How can I do that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run python script only if it's not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968080/run-python-script-only-if-its-not-running)

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a lock file like this:

```
import os
import sys
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    path_lock_file = os.path.join(path_dir, ".lock")
    if os.path.isfile(path_lock_file):
        sys.exit(0)
    with open(path_lock_file, "w") as f:
        pass
        
    # You python code down
    time.sleep(10)  # Simulation of you script duration
    # You python code up

    os.remove(path_lock_file)
```

(Tested)
This is NOT the best practice but it is cross Platform.

Comment: Why do you use `os._exit` instead of `sys.exit` ?

Comment: Because the lib os is already imported. But it doesn t matter (not an expert in exiting script). I don t know the difference.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591350/what-is-difference-between-sys-exit0-and-os-exit0

Comment: worked for me, but i dont want creare file like .lock
because when remove that work again, 
I do not want the user to have control over it